# Blender 3D with python. Существует ли возможность рендеринга видео в блендере, запуская его в -background, кроме рендеринга по кадрам и склейки

Tags: python, blender

У меня есть сервер который скриптом запускает рендер определенной модели. 1 фрейм рендерится ~3 секунды, выходит что для пятисекундного видео требуется примерно 120 фреймов, что занимает очень большое количество времени. Есть ли другие возможности для реализации?

Comment: Есть куча разных возможностей - можно оптимизировать сцену и настройки рендера, использовать EEVEE вместо Cycles, экспортировать в gltf и рендерить прямо браузером. Смотря какая у вас задача.

Comment: @Crantisz На данный момент используется EEVEE, практически максимально оптимизирована сцена, модели, текстуры. Сервер (blender -background) берет модель, применяет текстуры с нужными параметрами, рендерит 120 фреймов и создает видео. Все это занимает около минуты. Так вот существуют ли еще какие-нибудь способы делать то же самое, но быстрее. В основном самое затратное по времени это сохранение рендера каждого фрейма, для дальнейшего преобразования в видео.

Comment: Рендерить можно сразу видео

Comment: @Crantisz можно подробнее?

Comment: Ставите формат вывода ffmpeg, можно выбрать различные кодеки и контейнеры